# Golang Function Call Without Parentheses

Tags: function, go

I am going through the Golang tutorials on their website and am confused by code similar to this that I've simplified and reproduced here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    a := math.Sqrt2
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

This prints `1.4142135623730951` in the sandbox. Replacing `a := math.Sqrt2` with `a := math.Sqrt(2)` does the same thing but I'm confused how the function can be called without parentheses. `math.Sqrt` is not a function pointer here (there is no `math.Sqrt2` function anyway, it's a function being passed without any parentheses. The function in the Go documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Sqrt) is listed as: `func Sqrt(x float64) float64` i.e. with the parameter. So how does that work? Is it just because `math.Sqrt()` is a simplistic function that Go can assume it's a `float64` without the parentheses passed? Am I missing something?

If it helps, I found this phenomenon [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) in the tutorials on line 14, originally. If anyone could explain this feature to me, that would be awesome. I'd love to learn about it.

Comment: `math.Sqrt2` is a constant https://golang.org/pkg/math/#pkg-constants https://golang.org/src/math/const.go

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing special happening here. `math.Sqrt2` is a constant. You can find the other constants in the `math` package in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#pkg-constants).

In general, go doesn't really have any "magic". So if something feels a bit magical, its more than likely just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Got it! I was overthinking it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "go doesn't really have any "magic"" --- unless it does: expressions may behave differently depending on the context. Eg: as a part of a composite expression vs as a part of `return` (multiple value returns). To me - that's totally counter-intuitive magic